# Reloading TableView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a textfield that users enter the city and also tableview to populate cities that user chooses. However once user add a new city, my table does not reload and for that reason data does not update on tableview. I do not know what I am missing. I have attached my code as well as screenshot.

```
#import "AddCityViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AddCityViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddCityViewController
@synthesize addCityTF;
@synthesize myTableView;
@synthesize tableData;
@synthesize myString;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    myString=@"Houston,London,Istanbul,Tokyo";
    NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Data is :%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:24];


    return cell;
}


- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString* newString=[myString stringByAppendingString:addCityTF.text];
    NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    [myTableView reloadData];
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Main2Detail" sender:self];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding ',' while appending another string and wrong string for making the array, I think here is the problem:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {

    NSString* tempString=[myString stringByAppendingString:@","];
    NSString* newString=[tempString stringByAppendingString:addCityTF.text];
    NSArray *array = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    [myTableView reloadData];
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Main2Detail" sender:self];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit:**

Better way would be don't use sting, just use a `NSMutableArray`. in viewDidLoad do this:

```
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tableDate addObject: @"Houston"];
[tableDate addObject: @"London"];
[tableDate addObject: @"Istanbul"];
[tableDate addObject: @"Tokyo"];
```

Then In you a `addBtnClicked` just do this:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    [tableDate addObject: addCityTF.text];
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```